# How should I solute this error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python-3.x

This is my one part of python code

```
 f = textParse(open('email/spam/%d.txt', encoding="UTF-8" % i))
        wordList = f.read()
        docList.append(wordList)
        fullText.extend(wordList)
        classList.append(1)
```

and when I run it, it has this error, "not all arguments converted during string formatting", someone in internet say the explains that the number of parameters before and after % does not correspond to, I don't understand how to solute this error.

Comment: Start with indenting it properly.

Comment: The second half of your call to `open` tries to perform the string formatting `"UTF-8" % i`.

Comment: Sorry, @Arndt Jonasson I don't understand your mean, can you talk more details? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable `i` which you want to insert in a string, but you are putting it in the wrong place.

The call `open('email/spam/%d.txt', encoding="UTF-8" % i)` gives two arguments to `open`, one positional, and one by keyword:

1st argument: `'email/spam/%d.txt'`

2nd argument: `encoding="UTF-8" % i`

The `encoding` keyword gets the value `"UTF-8" % i`. This is nonsense, because `i` doesn't belong there, and that is where the complaint comes from: the `%` format gets no modifiers but one value, and that's one value too much.

What you want are these two arguments to `open`:

1st argument: `'email/spam/%d.txt' % i`

2nd argument: `encoding="UTF-8"`

Putting it together, you have

`open('email/spam/%d.txt' % i, encoding="UTF-8")`